# ggplot's geom_vline returns object not found for reactive variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to plot a vertical line on a plot in shiny, where the x intercept is a function of two of the user inputs. The variable is used in other outputs, so I am creating it an storing it in a variable. I can print the variable in an renderText so I know the calculation is correct, however ggplot is returning "object 'xintercept' not found". Below is the server function that isn't working. Note the ggplot call, when the geom_vline is removed, works find. Furthermore if the time_after_formation() is wrapped in a renderText works fine too.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(

        # Inputs
        sidebarPanel(
          numericInput(inputId = 'lon', label="Longitude:", value=-20),
          numericInput(inputId = 'lat', label="Lattitude:", value=20),
          numericInput(inputId = 'time_bp', label="Time:", value=65)
          ), 
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput(outputId="ocean_sub", width="auto", height="200px")
          )))


server = function(input, output){
  elementwise.all.equal <- Vectorize(function(x, y) {isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))})
  seafloor_age_drop = data.table(lon=-20, lat=20, age=150)
  setnames(floor_age_drop, c("lon", "lat", "age"))
  setkey(floor_age_drop, lon, lat)

  # Make model 
  model_age = seq(0,200, by=0.1)
  crosby_depth = 
    ifelse(model_age <=75, 2652+324*sqrt(model_age), 
           ifelse(model_age>75 & model_age <=160, 5028+5.26*model_age-250*sin(((model_age-75)/30)), 
                  ifelse(model_age>160, 5750,NA)))
  crosby_model = data.frame(age=model_age, depth=crosby_depth)



  # Reactives 
  age_from_grid = reactive({floor_age_drop[.(round(input$lon, digits=1), round(input$lat, digits=1)),'age']})
  time_after_floor_formation = reactive({age_from_grid() - input$time_bp})
  depth_crosby = reactive({crosby_model$depth[elementwise.all.equal(crosby_model$age, round(time_after_floor_formation(), 1))]
    })

  output$ocean_sub=renderPlot({
    ggplot(crosby_model, aes(x=age, y=depth)) + geom_line() +
 scale_y_reverse(lim=c(6000, 2500)) +
 geom_vline(xintercept=time_after_floor_formation(), colour='red')})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: Changed with a (hopefully) fully reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the plot in a reactive environment and then you use render plot for plotting it something like this:

```
 p = reactive({ggplot(my_model, aes(x=age, y=depth)) + geom_line() +
    scale_y_reverse(lim=c(6000, 2500)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=time_after_formation(), colour='red')})

output$ocean_sub = renderPlot({p})
```

**EDITED**
I found your problem and it is that the variable is `data.table` and that's why it doesn't work. just rap it up in `as.numeric` and it works perfect

```
 ggplot(crosby_model, aes(x=age, y=depth)) + geom_line() +
      scale_y_reverse(lim=c(6000, 2500)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(time_after_floor_formation()), colour='red')
```

Comment: I can't get that to work either - the plot no longer throws an error, but dissapears instead. I've changed my OP with a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @MurrayHoggett I don't know why you say is reproducible if it uses a .csv data, use something like mtcars

Comment: the .csv contents was in the question, but now altered so a single line csv equivalent is read in. Code now works on copy and paste.